# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (Intellij generated files)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup with JPA + Hibernate to work with my Oracle database. I connected Intellij to my datasource and then generated the persistence mapping using the database schema. However every time I run the following code I get an

> error(java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Maven + Hibernate + Oracle");
    PersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistence();
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = persistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "NewPersistenceUnit",new HashMap());

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    AdministrationUser user = new AdministrationUser();

    user.setUserName("mjh");
    user.setName("Brendan");
    user.setCreateDate(Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0"));
    user.setCreateBy("Brendan");
    user.setModDate(Timestamp.valueOf("2007-09-23 10:10:10.0"));
    user.setModBy("Brendan");

    entityManager.persist(user);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The persistence.xml and persistence class looks like this:

```
public class AdministrationUser {
    private long administrationUserId;
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp createDate;
    private String createBy;
    private Timestamp modDate;
    private String modBy;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "administrationUserId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
    public long getAdministrationUserId() {
        return administrationUserId;
    }

    public void setAdministrationUserId(long administrationUserId) {
        this.administrationUserId = administrationUserId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 64)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 64)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 15)
    public String getCreateBy() {
        return createBy;
    }

    public void setCreateBy(String createBy) {
        this.createBy = createBy;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "modDate", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Timestamp getModDate() {
        return modDate;
    }

    public void setModDate(Timestamp modDate) {
        this.modDate = modDate;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "modBy", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 15)
    public String getModBy() {
        return modBy;
    }

    public void setModBy(String modBy) {
        this.modBy = modBy;
    }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>edu.rit.its.coopEval.model.AdministrationUser</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have intentionally removed the url and password and username but within my code they are correct because I have used the exact same url, username, and password to connect to the database in toad and create the tables. I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: I assume your table in the database is also called "administration_user"?

Comment: yeah its called "AdministrationUser"

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
```

To your persitence unit. Otherwise, my guess would be you need to add an `@Table(name = "<whatever its called>")` to your entity.

EDIT:

After some more research on my part, it looks like for Hibernate, you may need this instead:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

I dont know if having it set as an attribute like youre doing works.

Comment: unfortunately tried all these suggestion but had no result